# Can you use the Windows 7 firewall to close ports over VPN?

Tags: windows-7, firewall, windows-firewall

I use VPN connection (specifically [ipredator](https://www.ipredator.se/)) for browsing over unsecured WiFi connections from my laptop (in coffee shops, etc.) - but at the other end of the VPN connection, all my ports are open to the internet.

I'm only using this connection for web browsing, so is there a way I can setup a software firewall to only open a few ports over that connection? I'm using Windows 7, so a solution using the built in firewall would be great - but if that's not possible, what other options do I have?